# Load admin bar without wp_head or wp_footer

Tags: php, functions, wp-head, admin-bar

Is there any possible way to load admin bar without wp_head or wp_footer? If no, so maybe there is a way to load wp_head() or wp_footer() to catch only admin bar functions, styles and scripts? Is this even possible in worpdress?

For example: `wp_head(load_admin_bar());` or something like that.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, the only solutions which worked was to call admin bar directly.

```
if (current_user_can('administrator') || current_user_can('editor')) {
 wp_admin_bar_render();
}
```